# Create box-shadow to drop-shadow mixin

Tags: css, stylus

I'm trying to write a mixin that should take as argument a CSS `box-shadow` and convert it to a `filter: drop-shadow()`.

```
// mixin
drop-shadow($shadows)
  $array = split(',', $shadows)
  $dropShadows = ()

  for $shadow in $array
    push($dropShadows, 'drop-shadow(' + $shadow + ')') 

  filter: unquote(join(' ', $dropShadows))

// usage
body
  drop-shadow: 0 0 1px, 0 0 1px
```

The problem is that I must pass the value of `drop-shadow` as string to make it work, if I pass it as array, it doesn't...

```
// works
drop-shadow: '0 0 1px, 0 0 1px'

// doesn't work
drop-shadow: 0 0 1px, 0 0 1px
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, found the solution:

```
// custom property (mixin) which allows you to define a box-shadow that will be
// rendered as `filter: drop-shadow()`
//
// usage:
// drop-shadow: 2px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
// => filter: drop-shadow(2px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5))

drop-shadow()
  $array = arguments
  $dropShadows = ()

  for $shadow in $array
    push($dropShadows, 'drop-shadow(' + $shadow + ')')

  filter: unquote(join(' ', $dropShadows))
```

This will accept rgb(a) or hsl(a) colors and works exactly like a `box-shadow`

Answer (score -2):

The Mixin you're looking is for LESS, SASS or what?

I've created a LESS mixin for box-shadow and it's pretty simple

```css
.box-shadow(@shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.25)) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @shadow;
     -moz-box-shadow: @shadow;
          box-shadow: @shadow;
}
```

Usage:

```css
.mybox {
  .box-shadow(0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
}
```

If I don't pass any param, it takes the default param.

The implementation is similar for SASS as well.

Comment: I'm using `stylus`, it's in the tags